# Как правильно объединить DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть три DataFrame:

1. Список всех пользователей
2. Список всех товаров
3. Запись того, что человек покупал этот товар

В первом есть идентификатор пользователя
Во втором есть идентификатор товара
В третьем есть идентифкатор пользователя и идентификатор товара

Мне нужно переписать их в один дф такого вида

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=['userID', 'itemID', ‘purchased‘])
```

Где `purchased` - флаг, что пользователь купил товар или нет, то бишь 1 и 0. Там должны быть все товары и все пользователи

Как можно правильно объединить DataFrame?

Comment: А сколько всего товаров и сколько всего пользователей? Вы понимаете, что записей будет первое умножить на второе, и это может в память не влезть вообще? )   Или это чисто учебный кейс?

Comment: Как-то, может, и можно, но без примера исходных данных в воспроизводимом виде и желаемого результата, как этого требуют правила сайта, помочь вам будет практически не возможно. Пока не будет нормального вопроса, буду голосовать за его закрытие.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь методом [DataFrame.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
res = df1.merge(df2, how="cross").merge(df3, how="all", indicator=True)
```

PS код в ответе не тестировался по причине отсутствия воспроизводимого примера данных в вопросе.